# how to get not matched record in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a tables like below

tableName: users

[image]

tableName: projects

[image]

tableName: user_project

[image]

So i want to get users who are not a part of project "1".

i tried like this but no luck

```
SELECT u.id, u.username
FROM testdb.user_project up
LEFT JOIN testdb.users u
ON up.userId = u.id
WHERE up.projectId=1 AND u.id IS NULL
```

My expected output

```
id  | username
--------------
3   | u3
4   | u4
```

can you please help me out of this

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please can you put the content of your table as text/script. Your images are blocked and I dont have any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query should work

```
select u.*
from users u
where u.id not in (select userId from user_project where projectId = 1)
```

Comment: You need to add DISTINCT to the select or you will get duplicate results

Comment: I added DISTINCT,  now it is giving the correct result.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6cd194c05a63b34315a6fe2628839121
@forpas

Comment: good point i have updated it. but it's still not a memory-optimized query if the DB is too big. @forpas

Answer (score 0):

use not exists

```
select u.* from users u     
where not exists ( select 1 from user_project up
      where up.userid= u.id and up.projectid=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want the users that are not associated with Project 1 in the relation table. You can do that using "where not exists".

The solution is better, cause exists removes the need to take care of duplicate values, cause one single occurrence is enough to match (or not match) the definition.

```
select
    u.id
  , u.username
from users u
where not exists (
  select
    1
  from user_project up
  where 1=1
    and up.projectID = 1
    and up.userId = u.id
)
```

Comment: I edited the distinct away, since it's not needed. It accidentally slipped in while I was typing another solution.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT u.id, u.username
FROM testdb.user_project up
LEFT JOIN testdb.users u
ON up.userId = u.id
WHERE up.projectId <> 1;
```

Comment: Your query is wrong: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d87c2512cc3aca23e82251ff6f399351

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.